# It´s possible make a triangle pattern in div background, only css3/html? How do it?

Tags: html, css

I need create a pattern background for one div, with fluid width. Like a background image. I would want if is possible make it only css3, and how to do.

[image: Pattern base it's:]

Triangle: height: 27px Width: 46px

[image: The pattern effetc is it]

Comment: I think the best way to achieve this is with a sprite and an image with repeat

Comment: This is a solution indeed but a bad markup also

Comment: There's loads of shapes on here http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Why my questin is marked with -1 point? I think it is pertinent! :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a repeating background.

CSS

```
.pattern {
    background-image: linear-gradient(319deg, black 16px, transparent 17px), linear-gradient(39deg, black 16px, transparent 17px);
    background-size: 54px 23px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You need 2 diferent backgrounds, one for each half of the triangle. The angle and size is the tricky part.

Browser requests: multiple background image, gradients.

I have set for the gradints only the last w3c syntax, you can make that work in older browsers using the prefixed versions

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QeZG6/)

Comment: Thank you it's just this! :)

Answer (score 0):

This creates a triangle with the sizes u gave

```
width: 0px;
background-color:#423434;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 27px 23px 0 23px;
border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
```

Comment: I didn´t explain it well. I need create a pattern background for one div, with fluid width. Like a background image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is!

Html

```
    <div id="leftTri"></div>
    <div id="tri"></div>
    <div id="rightTri"></div>
```

CSS

```
    #leftTri{
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-bottom:27px solid green;
        border-right:46px solid transparent;
        float:left;
    }

    #tri{
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-bottom:27px solid green;
        border-left:46px solid transparent;
        border-right:46px solid transparent;
        float:left;
    }

    #rightTri{
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-bottom:27px solid green;
        border-left:46px solid transparent;
        float:left;
    }
```

Here is a link to a JSFiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/Fdng8/2/

Comment: I didn´t explain it well. I need create a pattern background for one div, with fluid width. Like a background image. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. You can even use triangle generator [here](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

Comment: Why somebody doesn't like this answer? I gave a link to generator where he can create any type of triangle(s) with using only css. Is jsfiddle the only type of link for implementation acceptable ?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but maybe because only link answers are considered as low quality.... try to improve your answer with some example code and provide some explanation your self not copy paste. If the link you post goes down in the future then this answer is useless.

Comment: I didn´t explain it well. I need create a pattern background for one div, with fluid width. Like a background image. Thanks